# How to scrape multiple html page in parallel with beautifulsoup in python?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, beautifulsoup, python-multithreading

I'm making a webscraping app in Python with Django web framework. I need to scrape multiple queries using beautifulsoup library. Here is snapshot of code that I have written:

```
for url in websites:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    links = soup.find_all("a", {"class":"dev-link"})
```

Actually here the scraping of webpage is going sequentially, I want to run it in parallel manner. I don't have much idea about threading in Python.
can someone tell me, How can I do scrape in parallel manner? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how many webpage are you trying to scrape at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
import threading

def fetch_links(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    return soup.find_all("a", {"class": "dev-link"})

threads = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_links, args=(url,))
           for url in websites]

for t in thread:
    t.start()
```

Downloading web page content via `requests.get()` is a blocking operation, and Python threading can actually improve performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multithreading then,

```
import threading
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Scraper(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadId, name, url):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.id = threadId
        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        r = requests.get(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find_all("a")
        return links
#list the websites in below list
websites = []
i = 1
for url in websites:
    thread = Scraper(i, "thread"+str(i), url)
    res = thread.run()
    # print res
```

this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to python and scraping, [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) is probably the way to go.

scrapy is using [twisted mertix](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) library for parallelism so you dont have to worry about threading and the [python GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

If you must use beautifulsoap check [this library](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-beautifulsoup) out