# Continuously probing multiple ULRs with fewer threads, how to control threads

Tags: python, multithreading

**Background:**

I want to monitor say 100 URLs (take a snapshot, and stores it if content is different from previous), my plan is to using urllib.request to scan them every x minutes, say x=5, non-stop.

So I can't use a single for loop and sleep, as I want to kick off detection for ULR1, and then kick off URL2 almost simultaneously.

```
while TRUE:
  for url in urlList:
    do_detection()
    time.sleep(sleepLength)
```

Therefore I should be using pool? But I should limit the thread to a small amount that my CPU can handle (can't set to 100 threads if I have 100 ULRs)

**My question:**

Even I can send the 100 URLs in my list to ThreadPool(4) with four threads, how shall I design to control each thread to handle the 100/4=25 URLs, so the thread probes URL1, sleep(300) before next probe to URL1, and then do URL2.... ULR25 and goes back to URL1...?  I don't want to wait for 5 min*25 for a full cycle.

Psuedo code or examples will be great help! I can't find or think a way to make looper() and detector() behave as needed?

(I think [How to scrap multiple html page in parallel with beautifulsoup in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245451/how-to-scrap-multiple-html-page-in-parallel-with-beautifulsoup-in-python) this is close but not exact answer)

Maybe something like this for each thread? I will try to work out how to split the 100 items to each thread now. using pool.map(func, iterable[, chunksize]) takes a list and I can set chunksize to 25.

```
def one_thread(Url):

    For url in Url[0:24]:
          CurrentDetect(url)
    if 300-timelapsed>0:
        remain_sleeping=300-timtlapsed
    else:
        remain_sleeping=0


    sleep (remain_sleeping)

    For url in Url[0:24]:
          NextDetect()
```

The non-working code I am trying to write:

```
import urllib.request as req
import time
def url_reader(url = "http://stackoverflow.com"):

    try
        f = req.urlopen(url)
        print (f.read())

    except Exception as err
        print (err)

def save_state():
    pass
    return []

def looper (sleepLength=720,urlList):
    for url in urlList: #initial save
        Latest_saved.append(save_state(url_reader(url))) # return a list
    while TRUE:
        pool = ThreadPool(4) 


        results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
        time.sleep(sleepLength)  # how to parallel this? if we have 100 urls, then takes 100*20 min to loop?
        detector(urlList) #? use last saved status returned to compare?

def detector (urlList):




    for url in urlList:
            contentFirst=url_reader(url)

            contentNext=url_reader(url)

            if contentFirst!=contentNext:
                save_state(contentFirst)
                save_state(contentNext)
```

Comment: There is a suggestion to use scrapy, which has built-in thread allocation?

Comment: Take a look at [17.4.2.1. ThreadPoolExecutor Example](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example).

Comment: Have you figured it out with Python official example? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install **requests**,

```
pip install requests
```

if you want to use the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import concurrent.futures
import requests
import queue
import threading

# URL Pool
URLS = [
    # Put your urls here
]

# Time interval (in seconds)
INTERVAL = 5 * 60

# The number of worker threads
MAX_WORKERS = 4

# You should set up request headers
# if you want to better evade anti-spider programs
HEADERS = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    #'Host': None,
    'If-Modified-Since': '0',
    #'Referer': None,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.62 Safari/537.36',
}

############################

def handle_response(response):
    # TODO implement your logics here !!!
    raise RuntimeError('Please implement function `handle_response`!')

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(session, url):
    #print('load_url(session, url={})'.format(url))
    response = session.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # You can refactor this part and
        # make it run in another thread
        # devoted to handling local IO tasks,
        # to reduce the burden of Net IO worker threads
        return handle_response(response)

def ThreadPoolExecutor():
    return concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKERS)

# Generate a session object
def Session():
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update(HEADERS)
    return session

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor, Session() as session:
    if not URLS:
        raise RuntimeError('Please fill in the array `URLS` to start probing!')

    tasks = queue.Queue()

    for url in URLS:
        tasks.put_nowait(url)

    def wind_up(url):
        #print('wind_up(url={})'.format(url))
        tasks.put(url)

    while True:
        url = tasks.get()

        # Work
        executor.submit(load_url, session, url)

        threading.Timer(interval=INTERVAL, function=wind_up, args=(url,)).start()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot KaiserKatze! I tried the code and it stuck in load_url() not finishing session.get(url). I will do some debugging, maybe removing some locking or test with a simpler action rather than read url, because I can see first 2 workers launched but immediately other urls also submitted, maybe blocking the queue or something?

Comment: Most likely, 1 session object can't be used by 2 thread at the same time?

Comment: Below is the immediate output (at once, then hung)
url1 popleft OK
load_url function launched 
#(but not finishing session.request, I also tried with each load with its own call to init_request for a new session object)
url2 popleftOK
load_url function launched 
url3
load_url function launched 
url4
url5
load_url
url6
load_url
url7
load_url
url8
load_url
url9
load_url
load_url

Comment: @LanSi Oh, I just debugged my code. And here you are.