# Selenium Webdriver is not scrolling to click the load more button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to build a verge archives scraper for news headlines, my primary aim is to scrape data from a given month and year. The code was working some days back and it was scrolling properly but now it is unable to scroll and it is getting stuck every time. I am trying to scroll by the Action chain of CTRL+END but it does not work. I tried other ways too, but no luck

```
def scrolling_func(wait,driver):
print("It is trying to scroll")
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 5

last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('END').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    load_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.p-button')
    # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", load_button)
    element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.p-button')))
    # ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(load_button).click().perform()  
    load_button.click()   
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
# driver.delete_all_cookies()
time.sleep(1)
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('HOME').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

And the scraper is

```
def scraper(years,months):
PATH = r"C:\Users\astar\Stock market tutorials\chromedriver_win64\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.use_chromium = True


options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH,options=options)

driver.maximize_window()


urls = parse_dates(years,months)

final_headlines = []
final_dates = []
final_links = []

for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    done=True
    while done:
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
            scrolling_func(wait,driver)
        except:
            done=False
    ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('HOME').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041008/how-to-find-elements-by-class
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732958/python-parallel-execution-with-selenium
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245451/how-to-scrape-multiple-html-page-in-parallel-with-beautifulsoup-in-python
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45816619/selenium-firefox-webdriver-for-python-keyerror-value
    num_articles = soup.find("h1",class_="p-page-title").text
    current = num_articles[num_articles.find("for")+4:num_articles.find("(")]
    articles_num = num_articles[num_articles.find("(")+1:-1]
    titles = soup.find_all("h2",class_="c-entry-box--compact__title")
    dates = soup.find_all("time",class_="c-byline__item")

    if articles_num != len(titles):
        logger.warning("Actual #articles {} and #scraped articles {} for {}".format(articles_num,len(titles),current))
    print(len(titles),len(dates))

    headlines_results = map(title_extractor,titles)
    dates_results = map(date_extractor,dates)
    links_results = map(link_extractor,titles)

    
    def list_process(gens):
        return [gen for gen in gens]
    
    headlines = list_process(headlines_results)
    dates = list_process(dates_results)
    links = list_process(links_results)

    final_headlines.extend(headlines) 
    final_dates.extend(dates) 
    final_links.extend(links)

    time.sleep(15)

print(len(final_headlines),len(final_dates),len(final_links))    

assert len(final_headlines)==len(final_dates)==len(final_links), f'Different lengths of headlines {len(headlines)} and date {len(dates)}'
data = {"Headlines":final_headlines,"Dates":final_dates,"Links":final_links}
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 
df.to_csv('file1.csv') 
return df
```

if **name** == "**main**":
scraper(["2021"],["3"])

As I said, it is unable to scroll, it was working well some days back but now it is breaking. Also earlier I had the issue of unable to load the entire list of the page as it was getting stuck. Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use `css` selectors try the following for scrolling:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",driver.find_element_by_css_selector(.your_css_selector))
```

Or, if you use `xpath`:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",driver.find_element_by_xpath(.your_xpath_selector))
```

**Load more** should be the element which locator you need.

Check here to understand the difference between `scrollIntoView` and `moveToElement` They are more reliable than what you use now. [scrollIntoView vs moveToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement)

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too, but it is still not working. It is not scrolling into the view. It was working well a few days ago but now it is breaking and I don't know why. Do you think this is a server-side problem?